# Using UNC path with window.open

Tags: javascript

I have two servers: Server 1 and Server 2

My application is installed on Server 1. Server 2 contains some .PDF files.

I have created a Shared Drive.

Via UNC path, I am able to open PDF files folder from Server 1 as below:

```
\\Server2\Files\a.pdf
```

This UNC path I want to use when I want to open PDF files in a new browser window using javascript.

I tried using:

```
window.open("\\Server2\Files\a.pdf")
```

this is not working.

I also tried:

```
window.open("file://Server2/Files/a.pdf")
```

this is also not opening file nor giving error.

How to use UNC path to open file from Server 2?

Comment: Try 
`window.open("file://///Server2/Files/a.pdf")`

Comment: Tried this as well. Not working. No errors also.

Comment: Yes. Five slashes. Not opening.

Comment: can the machine you are trying it from see it at all ? window.open('file://server/folder/file');

Comment: you could set up something on the backend on server one that can be hit from the web to fetch documents from server 2 via the UNC path, but I dont think what youre trying to do is possible otherwise.  But if I'm wrong Id be interested in seeing an answer.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Rooster I created Shared Drive. From Server 1 Windows if I type \\Server2\Files\a.pdf, it is opening.

Comment: @dman2306 IE  8 and Firefox.

Comment: Is the page that calls window.open accessed via http://? If so you may be running into a security feature described here. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_%3a_Issues_%3a_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work If that is the case, what web server are you using? If it is iis you could make a virtual directory on server 1 that points to the share on server 2

Comment: @dman2306 Yes the page that uses Window.open is accessed via http://. I am using IIS.

Comment: Check the js console in Firefox to see if it is as that article describes. If so, I'd go with a virtual directory

Comment: @dman2306 Ok. Will check this and let you know. But why five slashes are not working?

Comment: Because of security. Do you like the idea of websites having links to files stored on your local file system? I don't. You can't have a website provide links to resources that exist on the user's pc. The file scheme means it's a file on your pc even though I'm this case it is really on another server.

Comment: @dman2306 Can I disable this feature in Firefox?

Comment: @dman2306 Can you please illustrate the steps to create virtual directory on server 1 which points to server 2 and how to call this directory from javascript?